# iOS Reloading two tableView sections

Tags: ios, tableview, reload

How can I reload two sections in my tableView that are not adjacent? For example, if I want to reload sections 0 and 4. I can't use

```
[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange: withRowAnimation:];
```

because it will reload all the sections in between, right?

I also tried using successive calls of

```
[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex: withRowAnimation:]
```

but it didn't work and I got this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (8) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

**EDIT:** Sorry I forgot to mention that on my update the number of rows changes for each section reloaded.

Comment: how about using UITableView beginUpdates & endUpdates & inserting or updating new rows in between?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454708/nsinternalinconsistencyexception-invalid-number-of-rows

Comment: Have you even looked at the documentation ?? -> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadSections:withRowAnimation: (reloadSections:withRowAnimation:)

Comment: Yes I did. I saw that reloadSections:withRowAnimation: takes an NSIndexSet. But the only methods I saw in NSIndexSet to create a set with multiple indexes was to use a range. I want to update two sections that are not adjacent. Is there a way to create an NSIndexSet that isn't made from a range? I didn't see a way in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem by just reordering my reloadSections: calls so that only one section's data was changed before each reloadSections: call.

Comment: This bugged me and it seems that only reloading one section at a time made it all work.