# Unable to delete row in UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have 2 arrays that i need to remove data from when removing my row, and both appear to have that deleted. However when I slide to delete i get the following error:

> `[2078:568325] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView
>   _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3318.16.21/UITableView.m:1582 [2078:568325]
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
>   1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        audioPlayers[indexPath.row].stop()
        audioFiles.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        audioPlayers.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }

}
```

It seems to be erroring out on at deleteRowsAtIndexPaths.

Comment: what value do you return for the number of rows in a table view

Comment: @chrono Once you delete the data you need to reload the tableView. At the end try [tableView reloadData]

Comment: I return a count of my enumeratedDocumentDirectory function that returns a fileList of strings

Comment: @Akshay I threw that in there however its still throwing the same error. I  put it between the removeAtIndex and the tableView.deleteRows

Comment: @chrono try putting it after the delete and debug your code in that section, as it does not make sense to update table view and delete the item

Comment: well you need to make sure that the enumeratedDocumentDirectory function returns 1 less in file list of strings. You're getting this error because you delete a row but your numberOfRows still returns the same number of rows(not 1 less like it looks like it should be)

Comment: did you look at the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454708/nsinternalinconsistencyexception-invalid-number-of-rows

Comment: @Akshay I did try that, and i was still getting a similar error.

Comment: @JoshHamet I've attempted to remove the row from the document directory but i think i'm screwing something up functionality wise. 
     var directory = enumerateDocumentDirectory()
            directory.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your call to delete rows before removing the elements from your data model. Something like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        audioPlayers[indexPath.row].stop()
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        audioFiles.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        audioPlayers.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    }

}
```

Comment: Negatory. Thanks for the suggestion. It appears that its just not updating the rows in my document model

Comment: Do you mean you can't see your data model (audioFiles and audioPlayers) update after applying my solution?

Answer (score 0):

I make it like

```
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            managedObjectContext.deleteObject(fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject)
            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                print("error managed object context in dictionary table")
            }
        } else if editingStyle == .Insert {

        }    
    }
  func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
        switch type {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move:
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
            tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)
        }
    }

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
        switch type {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
            tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
            tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move:
            tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
            break
        }
    }
```